# What is the frequency to update exchange rate for eCommerce website with multiple currencies?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

We are including third party API to convert currency as per country selected in the dropdown. The steps are

1) Set currency in session/cookie
2) Have a lookup table of currency conversions stored somewhere (e.g. database) - convert it into the new price using the lookup table depending on whichever currency is set in your session/cookie.

Unable to decide how to set the cookie expiry time for lookup table for currency conversion. Is it good, if we do it twice in a day. As per our requirement we don't need exchange rate updating for every request.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the last data in the session as well. Like `Session["LastConversionDate"] = DateTime.Now`, and then upon the next request test whether `((DateTime)Session["LastConversionDate"]) < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-expirationInMinutes)`.